# Loop that checks if it exist in table and generate random string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, mysqli

I have a function that generates a random string

```
    $found = true;
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
$str = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
 while($found == true)
{
     $check1 = $baza->query("SELECT key_X FROM generatedkey WHERE generatekey = '$str'");;
    if(mysql_num_rows($check1)==0) {
        $found = false;
    } else {

       $str = generateRandomString();

    }
}
return $str;
$found = true;
}
```

I would like to know if it is correct because I don't know how to check it.
This function should work like this:

- generate random string
- check if string exist in table
- if exist (> create new)
- if don't exist
- return randomstring

Comment: a do-while loop would work fine for this do{generate string and then query}while(mysql_num_rows($check1)==0)
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: It's not correct, Pick one, the loop or recursion, not both.  Not to mention the random string is generated outside of the loop.  `$found` is also defined outside of the function, so it's undefined in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

```
$found = true; //defined outside the function

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
     //string is generated outside the loop
    $str = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);

    while($found == true) //found is undefined so this never runs
    {
         $check1 = $baza->query("SELECT key_X FROM generatedkey WHERE generatekey = '$str'");;
        if(mysql_num_rows($check1)==0) {
            $found = false;
        } else {
           $str = generateRandomString(); //recursion or a loop not both
        }
    }
    return $str;
    $found = true; //pointless
}
```

With a loop

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    while(true)
    {
        $str = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
        $check1 = $baza->query("SELECT key_X FROM generatedkey WHERE generatekey = '$str'");


        if(mysql_num_rows($check1)==0) break; //no results=unique, so bail out of the loop
    }
    return $str;
}
```

With recursion

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {

    $str = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
    $check1 = $baza->query("SELECT key_X FROM generatedkey WHERE generatekey = '$str'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($check1)!=0) $str=generateRandomString($length); //results=not unique, do recursion

    return $str;
}
```

PS. I'll let the prepared statement go here as it's just a random string, no user input.

**Personally**

I think using a loop is fine for this, the only thing I would add is to have it throw an exception if it does too many iterations. This is just one of those, it should never happen.

One thing to consider is `10` really isn't that long. We recently been having about a 2% fail rate on certificate codes, (8 long). The only thing I can come up with is they are non-unique collisions (This is a 3rd party LMS).  This system is about 6 years old, and I'm working on replacing it.  So depending on the frequency that you generate these, they are not infinite and over time the chance of a collision increases.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10, $max_iterations=100) {
    for($i=0;$i<$max_iterations;++$i){
        $str = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
        $check1 = $baza->query("SELECT key_X FROM generatedkey WHERE generatekey = '$str'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($check1)==0) return $str; //return when condition met
    }
    //if were here then we didn't return $str above
    throw new Exception("too many iterations");
}
```